# Json Data To desired format

Tags: python, json, arraylist

New to python and json parsing

Json Format:

Once I load the data and print the details of the columns as headers and traverse through the object, I can get them but the ask is to print it in a specific format as mentioned below which is becoming difficult to understand.

```
[
  {
    "table": {
      "cols": [
        "New Charges",
        "From",
        "To",
        "Quantity",
        "Rate",
        "Frequency",
        "Amount"
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "Bar Charges",
          "12/29/19",
          "12/29/19",
          "1.00",
          "$71.65",
          "One time",
          "$71.65"
        ],
        [
          "Dining Services",
          "12/31/19",
          "12/31/19",
          "1.00",
          "$17.90",
          "One time",
          "$17.90"
        ],
        [
          "Incontinence supplies",
          "12/18/19",
          "12/18/19",
          "1.00",
          "$55.32",
          "One time",
          "$55.32"
        ],
        [
          "Bar Charges",
          "01/11/20",
          "01/11/20",
          "1.00",
          "$73.75",
          "One time",
          "$73.75"
        ],
        [
          "Room - Assisted Living",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$4,695.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$4,695.00"
        ],
        [
          "Assisted Living Level 3",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$1,700.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$1,700.00"
        ],
        [
          "Basic Medication Management",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$275.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$275.00"
        ],
        [
          "Emergency Response Charge",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$30.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$30.00"
        ]
      ],
      "bbox": [
        118,
        1219,
        2371,
        1691
      ],
      "data": [
        [
          "New Charges",
          "From",
          "To",
          "Quantity",
          "Rate",
          "Frequency",
          "Amount"
        ],
        [
          "Bar Charges",
          "12/29/19",
          "12/29/19",
          "1.00",
          "$71.65",
          "One time",
          "$71.65"
        ],
        [
          "Dining Services",
          "12/31/19",
          "12/31/19",
          "1.00",
          "$17.90",
          "One time",
          "$17.90"
        ],
        [
          "Incontinence supplies",
          "12/18/19",
          "12/18/19",
          "1.00",
          "$55.32",
          "One time",
          "$55.32"
        ],
        [
          "Bar Charges",
          "01/11/20",
          "01/11/20",
          "1.00",
          "$73.75",
          "One time",
          "$73.75"
        ],
        [
          "Room - Assisted Living",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$4,695.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$4,695.00"
        ],
        [
          "Assisted Living Level 3",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$1,700.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$1,700.00"
        ],
        [
          "Basic Medication Management",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$275.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$275.00"
        ],
        [
          "Emergency Response Charge",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$30.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$30.00"
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "table": {
      "cols": [
        "Payments",
        "Date",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "Amount"
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "Electronic payment",
          "12/30/19",
          "12/30/19",
          "1.00",
          "$6,997.32One time",
          "($6,997.32)"
        ]
      ],
      "bbox": [
        114,
        957,
        2374,
        1053
      ],
      "data": [
        [
          "Payments",
          "Date",
          "",
          "",
          "",
          "Amount"
        ],
        [
          "Electronic payment",
          "12/30/19",
          "12/30/19",
          "1.00",
          "$6,997.32One time",
          "($6,997.32)"
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "table": {
      "cols": [
        "Credits",
        "From",
        "To",
        "Quantity",
        "Rate",
        "Frequency",
        "Amount"
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "$0.00"
        ]
      ],
      "bbox": [
        117,
        1087,
        2382,
        1200
      ],
      "data": [
        [
          "Credits",
          "From",
          "To",
          "Quantity",
          "Rate",
          "Frequency",
          "Amount"
        ],
        [
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "$0.00"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I am able to extract the headers for each column but how to convert it into below format:

```
#  {
#    "New Charges": "Bar Charges",
#    "From": "12/29/19",
#    "To": "12/29/19",
#    "Quantity": "1.00",
#    "Rate": "$71.65",
#    "Frequency": "One time",
#    "Amount": "$71.65"
#  },
```

Not looking for exact code but some suggestions and guidance is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will create key, value dictionaries using the column names:

```
tables_to_parse = [
  {
    "table": {
      "cols": [
        "New Charges",
        "From",
        "To",
        "Quantity",
        "Rate",
        "Frequency",
        "Amount"
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "Bar Charges",
          "12/29/19",
          "12/29/19",
          "1.00",
          "$71.65",
          "One time",
          "$71.65"
        ],
        [
          "Dining Services",
          "12/31/19",
          "12/31/19",
          "1.00",
          "$17.90",
          "One time",
          "$17.90"
        ],
        [
          "Incontinence supplies",
          "12/18/19",
          "12/18/19",
          "1.00",
          "$55.32",
          "One time",
          "$55.32"
        ],
        [
          "Bar Charges",
          "01/11/20",
          "01/11/20",
          "1.00",
          "$73.75",
          "One time",
          "$73.75"
        ],
        [
          "Room - Assisted Living",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$4,695.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$4,695.00"
        ],
        [
          "Assisted Living Level 3",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$1,700.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$1,700.00"
        ],
        [
          "Basic Medication Management",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$275.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$275.00"
        ],
        [
          "Emergency Response Charge",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$30.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$30.00"
        ]
      ],
      "bbox": [
        118,
        1219,
        2371,
        1691
      ],
      "data": [
        [
          "New Charges",
          "From",
          "To",
          "Quantity",
          "Rate",
          "Frequency",
          "Amount"
        ],
        [
          "Bar Charges",
          "12/29/19",
          "12/29/19",
          "1.00",
          "$71.65",
          "One time",
          "$71.65"
        ],
        [
          "Dining Services",
          "12/31/19",
          "12/31/19",
          "1.00",
          "$17.90",
          "One time",
          "$17.90"
        ],
        [
          "Incontinence supplies",
          "12/18/19",
          "12/18/19",
          "1.00",
          "$55.32",
          "One time",
          "$55.32"
        ],
        [
          "Bar Charges",
          "01/11/20",
          "01/11/20",
          "1.00",
          "$73.75",
          "One time",
          "$73.75"
        ],
        [
          "Room - Assisted Living",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$4,695.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$4,695.00"
        ],
        [
          "Assisted Living Level 3",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$1,700.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$1,700.00"
        ],
        [
          "Basic Medication Management",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$275.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$275.00"
        ],
        [
          "Emergency Response Charge",
          "02/01/20",
          "02/29/20",
          "1.00",
          "$30.00",
          "Monthly",
          "$30.00"
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "table": {
      "cols": [
        "Payments",
        "Date",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "Amount"
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "Electronic payment",
          "12/30/19",
          "12/30/19",
          "1.00",
          "$6,997.32One time",
          "($6,997.32)"
        ]
      ],
      "bbox": [
        114,
        957,
        2374,
        1053
      ],
      "data": [
        [
          "Payments",
          "Date",
          "",
          "",
          "",
          "Amount"
        ],
        [
          "Electronic payment",
          "12/30/19",
          "12/30/19",
          "1.00",
          "$6,997.32One time",
          "($6,997.32)"
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "table": {
      "cols": [
        "Credits",
        "From",
        "To",
        "Quantity",
        "Rate",
        "Frequency",
        "Amount"
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "$0.00"
        ]
      ],
      "bbox": [
        117,
        1087,
        2382,
        1200
      ],
      "data": [
        [
          "Credits",
          "From",
          "To",
          "Quantity",
          "Rate",
          "Frequency",
          "Amount"
        ],
        [
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "n/a",
          "$0.00"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
]

def parse_table(table):
    cols = table['cols']
    rows = table['rows']
    formatted_rows = [{
        col:row_val for col, row_val in zip(cols, row)
    } for row in rows]
    return formatted_rows

parsed_tables = [parse_table(table['table']) for table in tables_to_parse]
```

Example row:

```
{
  'New Charges': 'Bar Charges',
  'From': '12/29/19', 
  'To': '12/29/19', 
  'Quantity': '1.00', 
  'Rate': '$71.65', 
  'Frequency': 'One time', 
  'Amount': '$71.65'
}
```